# Programmatically Export HighCharts graph in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, reactjs

Instead of using the default context buttons provided by HighCharts `exporting.js`, I want to programmatically trigger the export with a custom button.

In pure jQuery, it would look like this:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.exportChart();
});
```

So far, I've gotten the DOM node of the chart, but I can't actually call `exportChart` on it. My HighCharts graph (I'm using https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts by the way) in React is defined as:

```
var HighCharts = require('react-highcharts');
<HighCharts config={config} ref="chart"></HighCharts>
```

My button directs to this function, where I can get the HighCharts html element, but I can't trigger `exportChart`:

```
download_graph: function(){
    var node = this.refs.chart.getDOMNode();
    //What to do from here?
}
```

The value of `node` in the above function is:

```
<div class=​"chart" data-reactid=​".0.1.1.0.3" data-highcharts-chart=​"18">​…​</div>​
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Let me know which module for react do you use, https://github.com/jasonganub/react-highcharts or https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts ?

Comment: I am using [this](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts) module (https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts)

Comment: As I see in that example: http://kirjs.github.io/react-highcharts/ there are no reference to exporting module. Please ensure if author of that wrapper has any extension to support exporitng.

Comment: Yes, I can export already by including `exporting.js` from HighCharts itself (<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>). I know that there is no native support in kirjs's implementation of HighCharts in react, but I thought that there must be a way to support it.

Comment: Are you able to recreate full example on jsfiddle.net ?